# Область видимости коллбека функции findById

Tags: node.js, mongoose, асинхронность

```
var userProjects = [];

async.each(listOfProjects, function(elem, callback) {
    Project.findById(elem, function(err, project) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // этот userProjects, не имеет отношения к объявленному перед функцией
        userProjects.push(project);
    });
    callback();
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        log.debug(err);
        res.status(500).end();
        return next();
        // return next(err);
    }
        // Выводится пустой массив
        console.log(userProjects); // <-- []
        res.status(200);
        res.json( userProjects );
});
```

Как я понимаю, вышеуказанная анонимная функция выполняется асинхронно, в другой области видимости и там нет моего массива.

Я правильно понимаю? Каким путем можно пойти?

Comment: "в другой области видимости" - что Вы понимаете под этими словами? Массив - виден.

Comment: "этот userProjects, не имеет отношения к объявленному перед функцией" - а что это за `userProjects`, где он декларирован и создан? Строка `userProjects.push(project);` выполняется?

Comment: //Выводится пустой массив - А надо, чтобы выводился не пустой? Что надо-то?